# rShiny textOutput and Paragraph on same line

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to put a `renderText` element in the form of `textOutput` next to a header, but it keeps putting them on different lines.

`h1('This is the number:'), textOutput(output$number)`

This doesn't work either:

`p(h1('This is the number:'), textOutput(output$number))`

Anyone have any work arounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using css

```
ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
tags$head(tags$style("
                  #number{
                  display:inline
                  }")),
h1('This is the number:',style="display:inline"), textOutput("number")
)

)

server=function(input,output){
  output$number=renderText({5})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

or

```
ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
tags$head(tags$style("
                  #container * {  
   display: inline;
                     }")),
div(id="container",h1('This is the number:'), textOutput("number"))
)

)
```

Answer (score 9):

Construct everything in the server.R

```
output$textWithNumber <- renderText({ 
   paste("This is the number:", yourNumber)
})
```

Then in ui.R

```
h1(textOutput("textWithNumber"))
```

Comment: This doesn't allow each element to have different properties such as heading levels

Answer (score 1):

textOutput() has an inline flag (which I assume didn't exist when the previous answers were given). This means the text is wrapped in a span rather than a div, i.e.:

```
h1('This is the number:'), textOutput(output$number, inline = T)
```

Will be on one line, no need for custom CSS.