# How can I call data created in the server function for displaying values in the UI? R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am having such a hard time by getting this kinda thing where I build a data set inside the server function for plotting a treemap and displaying not only the graph in the main panel but info regarding the data in the sidebar panel. Could somebody please tell me how I can make this reactive to be able to be used like I'm trying in the code below, if UI was working just fine?
I've tried making dtd1 inside `reactive` earlier and then calling it inside the plot as `dtd1()` but it keeps on not working.

```
############################ GLOBAL #########################################

#1. App
if("shiny" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("shiny") }
library(shiny)

#2. Easier data handling
if("dplyr" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("dplyr") }
library(dplyr)

#3. Interactive graphs
if("plotly" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("plotly") }
library(plotly)


############################ UI #########################################
ui <- fluidPage( 
  # Set bullet size
  tags$style(type='text/css', "#select {font-size: 16px !important} "), 
  # 32px - h1() size || 24px - h2() size || 18.72px - h3() size || 16px - h4() size || 13.28px - h5() size
  navbarPage("Analysis", 
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(

                        h5(tags$li( tags$head(tags$style("
                        #container * {   display: inline;  }")),
                        div(id="container", textOutput("patent_scape_tag1")))
                        )
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotlyOutput("treemap")
               )
             )
  ))


############################ SERVER #########################################

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  dtd1 <- NULL
  output$treemap <- renderPlotly({ 
    dtd1 <<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
                                            5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", 
                                                                                "Carrot", "Mango", "Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", 
                                                                                "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"), class = "factor"), 
                           V2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
                                            7L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", 
                                                                    "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                 -13L))
    p <- plot_ly(
      dtd1,
      labels = ~ V1,
      parents = NA,
      values = ~ V2,
      type = 'treemap',
      hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
    )

    p
  })

  output$patent_scape_tag1 <- renderText({ 
    paste0("Topic ",
           as.character(dtd1$V1[which.max(dtd1$V2)]), 
           " reached the highest number!")
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is `dtd7` ?

Comment: You can't access `dtd1` from the UI, it is not available there. Add a `textOutput` or `uiOutput` in the UI and populate it from the server function.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent my mistake, it was dtd1 the whole thing that ain't working

Comment: `dtd1` has no columns `topic` and `n`.

Comment: Fixed it! @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: Ok. See the documentation of `renderUI` in the Shiny package. Give it a try and raise your voice if you don't manage.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent could manage as I edited my question thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250200/rshiny-textoutput-and-paragraph-on-same-line), but still can't figure how to align the tag with text, any ideas?