# How can I align the tag with the displayed text?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm using the code below to build a shiny app but I don't get why text displays below the tag, it's supossed to be in the same line, anybody knows how to fix it?
Fixed the first answear in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250200/rshiny-textoutput-and-paragraph-on-same-line) question to make it display the text I was aiming for, but the tag is missaligned! I don't know if there is something else needed to write in this question!

```
############################ GLOBAL #########################################

#1. App
if("shiny" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("shiny") }
library(shiny)

#2. Easier data handling
if("dplyr" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("dplyr") }
library(dplyr)

#3. Interactive graphs
if("plotly" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){ install.packages("plotly") }
library(plotly)


############################ UI #########################################
ui <- fluidPage( 
  # Set bullet size
  tags$style(type='text/css', "#select {font-size: 16px !important} "), 
  # 32px - h1() size || 24px - h2() size || 18.72px - h3() size || 16px - h4() size || 13.28px - h5() size
  navbarPage("Analysis", 
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(

                        h5(tags$li(textOutput("patent_scape_tag1")))
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotlyOutput("treemap")
               )
             )
  ))


############################ SERVER #########################################

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  dtd1 <- NULL
  output$treemap <- renderPlotly({ 
    dtd1 <<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
                                            5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", 
                                                                                "Carrot", "Mango", "Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", 
                                                                                "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"), class = "factor"), 
                           V2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
                                            7L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", 
                                                                    "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                 -13L))
    p <- plot_ly(
      dtd1,
      labels = ~ V1,
      parents = NA,
      values = ~ V2,
      type = 'treemap',
      hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
    )

    p
  })

  output$patent_scape_tag1 <- renderText({ 
    paste0("Topic ",
           as.character(dtd1$V1[which.max(dtd1$V2)]), 
           " reached the highest number!")
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do you put `tags$head` inside a `tags$li` ? That's very weird. `tags$head` should be at the beginning of `fluidPage`. That said, which tag are you talking about ? What is misaligned ?

Comment: `tag$li` is the one that I want. With missalignment I refer to the fact that it shows the tag and text below, not right next to it. I really don't know much about this coding and I was following the question I mentioned! But still, took off that many tags and left it just like this: `h5(tags$li(textOutput("patent_scape_tag1")))` but still doesn't give it to me in the same line.

Comment: Maybe you want `h5(tags$li(textOutput("patent_scape_tag1", inline=TRUE)))`? But i'm not sure why you have an `li` there at all. Are you trying to create a list of some sort?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes indeed, I display more than one of those tags in the `sidebarPanel` as a list of 5 or 6. That solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

```
ui <- fluidPage( 

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("#patent_scape_tag1 {display: list-item;}"))
  ),

  navbarPage("Analysis", 
             tabPanel("Home",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        textOutput("patent_scape_tag1")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        plotlyOutput("treemap")
                      )
             )
  )
)
```